# OpenGL ES: altering alpha of render without glColor?

Tags: opengl-es

I have a few VBOs with color data, and I wish to draw them with varying transparency.

However, I realise that to do this normally, I'd have to either change the alpha value on the color array, or to use a shader, but I'm on OpenGL ES 1.1 so that's no go..

Is there any other way to change transparency of objects as a whole, without having to go glColor?

Comment: What's wrong with `glColor()`?

Comment: The VBOs already have color data attached to them, and they differ for each vertex as well.